# Is it possible to use whitespace in format specifier

Tags: python, f-string

If I have following print statements:

```py
print("#"*80)
print(f"##{'':.^76}##")
print(f"##{'Hello World':.^76}##")
print(f"##{'':.^76}##")
print("#"*80)
```

I will get a nice border around my "Hello World" but with dots:

```bash
################################################################################
##............................................................................##
##................................Hello World.................................##
##............................................................................##
################################################################################
```

If I use a `' '` instead of the `.` in the second to fourth print statement, I will get a `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`.

How can replace the dot with whitespace or any other ascii symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it enough to simply remove the dot and leave a space?

So:

```py
print("#"*80)
print(f"##{'': ^76}##")
print(f"##{'Hello World': ^76}##")
print(f"##{'': ^76}##")
print("#"*80)
```

output will be:

```
################################################################################
##                                                                            ##
##                                Hello World                                 ##
##                                                                            ##
################################################################################
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just `{'': ^76}`

```
print("#"*80)
print(f"##{'': ^76}##")
print(f"##{'Hello World': ^76}##")
print(f"##{'': ^76}##")
print("#"*80)
```